# Question about dispatch_group_t results in two callbacks in a network request

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I use `dispatch_group_t` to handle my three network requests with the following code:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);

[self.permissionData removeAllObjects];
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [self getOneData];
});

[self.bannerData removeAllObjects];
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    [self getTwoData];
});

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView.mj_header endRefreshing];
});
```

and

```
- (void)getOneData {
    [self requestData:^(id  _Nullable datas, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if (error != nil) {
              [self.tableView.mj_header endRefreshing];
          } else {
              if ([datas isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                  self.datas = datas;
              }
              [self.tableView reloadData];
          }
    }];
}
```

This will cause the callbacks of both methods `getOneData` and `getTwoData` to go twice. I don't know why they both go twice, but if I don't use `dispatch_group_t`, there is no problem. May I ask why this is?

Answer (score 0):

As the work you are doing in your submitted blocks is, itself, asynchronous, you can't rely on `dispatch_group_async` to manage group entry and exit for you.

You need to call `dispatch_group_enter` before you call each function and `dispatch_group_leave` in the completion handler of each function.

With your current code, the group is entered when the block is submitted and the group is left when the submitted block is complete.

Because `requestData` is asynchronous, `getOneData` returns but the network operation is not complete.

As `getOneData` (and presumably `getTwoData`) is asynchronous there is little value to calling it from an asynchronous block.

You also have a bug where both your completion handler for `getOneData` and your `dispatch_group_notify` call `endRefreshing`. This will result in an "unbalanced calls" exception if there is an error in the first data request.

Answer (score 0):

The `dispatch_group_async` will enter the group immediately, and will leave the group when the called block returns. But the blocks are simply calling methods that launch asynchronous tasks, but doesn’t know when that work finishes. The net effect is that the dispatch group will be prematurely notified, as soon as these two asynchronous tasks are started, but not when this asynchronous work is complete.

So, the challenge is how to defer the dispatch group until the asynchronous work finishes. We would often reach for completion handler blocks:

```objectivec
- (void)getOneDataWithCompletion:(void (^ _Nullable)(void))completion {
    [self requestData:^(id _Nullable datas, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          …

          if (completion) {
              completion();
          }
    }];
}
```

And we would do the same with the second API call, too.

Having done that, we can now “enter” the group before making the asynchronous call and only “leave” the group in the completion handler block, e.g.:

```objectivec
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self getOneDataWithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self getTwoDataWithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    …
});
```

As a general rule, if you have an asynchronous method, it is prudent to give it completion handler block parameter that you call when the asynchronous method is done. And if you think you might not need that parameter, make it `_Nullable` (which is why I’m checking that it is not null before I call it).